# Add/remove table rows from multiple tables and insert into one table row

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have 4 tables in a normal html page. Three of these tables contain data that needs to be inserted into a 4th table. I also need the option to remove these rows in the 4th table and place back to the correct table the data originated from. I have this working for one example. Moving a row from Table1 and inserting it into Table2, then removing the row from Table2 and inserting back into Table1. There are add and remove buttons for each action. See jQuery below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Setup the "Move Me" links
$(".rowLink").click(function () {
    // get the row containing this link 
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");

    // find out in which table it resides
    var table = $(this).closest("table");

    // move it
    row.detach();

    if (table.is("#table1")) {
        $("#table2").append(row);
    }

        else {
        $("#table1").append(row);

    }   

});

 });

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('table a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: If you say you have this working, what exactly is your question?

Comment: Could you please post your HTML?

Comment: So you need to gather multiple rows from different tables and collect them in another table, but when removing them from this new table again, they must "return" to their original positions?

Answer (score 0):

with the assumption like simon, i came up with this soln...
just have the same name for the id of the table and the class of the rows inside it
this should solve it

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".rowlink").click(function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var table = $(this).closest("table");

            var IDofthetable = table.attr('id');
            var ClassoftheRow = row.attr("class");

            row.detach();

            if (ClassoftheRow==IDofthetable) {  // if it is in the parent table
                $("#tab4").append(row);  //move to table 4
            }
            else {
                $("#"+ClassoftheRow).append(row); //move to parent table
            }
        });
    });

 <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="Table1">
                    <tr class="Table1">
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Move Me 1" name="button" id="buttonTab1_1" class="rowlink" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="Table1">
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Move Me 1" name="button" id="buttonTab1_2" class="rowlink" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="Table1">
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Move Me 1" name="button" id="buttonTab1_3" class="rowlink" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table id="Table2">
                    <tr class="Table2">
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Move Me 2" name="button" id="buttonTab2_1" class="rowlink" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="Table2">
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Move Me 2" name="button" id="buttonTab2_2" class="rowlink" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="Table2">
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Move Me 2" name="button" id="buttonTab2_3" class="rowlink" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table id="Table3">
                    <tr class="Table3">
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Move Me 3" name="button" id="buttonTab3_1" class="rowlink" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="Table3">
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Move Me 3" name="button" id="buttonTab3_2" class="rowlink" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="Table3">
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Move Me 3" name="button" id="buttonTab3_3" class="rowlink" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="tab4">
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table
```

>